# P/Invoke changes the values of passed arguments

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, native, unmanaged

So I have this c++ function in a DLL

```
__declspec(dllexport) MOUSERAWDATA __stdcall GetMouseRawData(LPARAM lParam)
{
    UINT bufferSize = 0;
    BYTE *buffer = new BYTE[bufferSize];
    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, (LPVOID)buffer, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
    RAWINPUT *raw = (RAWINPUT*)buffer;
    MOUSERAWDATA data;
    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE)
    {
        data.longX = raw->data.mouse.lLastX;
        data.longY = raw->data.mouse.lLastY;
    }
    return data;
}
```

And the following is in my c# project:

```
[DllImport("RawInput.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern MouseRawData GetMouseRawData(IntPtr lParam);
.
.
.
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch(m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            if (AttachMouseListener(this.Handle))
                Console.WriteLine("It works!");
            break;
        case WM_INPUT:
            MouseRawData data = GetMouseRawData(m.LParam);
            break;
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
     }
}
```

When I run this code, the following value is passed to the GetMouseRawData

[image: The value being passed]

But for some reason the value of lParam at the C++ side is always different.

[image]

I this case 0x004fe95c = 5237084

Anyone knows why this happens?

Comment: Your pinvoke declaration does not match your C function.  Probably because of the MouseRawData declaration, we have the benefit of not seeing it, functions returning a struct are always tricky.  Favor bool GetMouseRawData(LPARAM lParam, MOUSERAWDATA* data) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating a buffer of 0 length. Then "asking" what size the buffer should be.  And then lying to GetRawInputData by telling them that your buffer is the correct size.  Move your buffer allocation to the point after the first call where you've learned the required size of the buffer.

```
UINT bufferSize = 0;
BYTE *buffer = new BYTE[bufferSize];
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, NULL, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, (LPVOID)buffer, &bufferSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER));
RAWINPUT *raw = (RAWINPUT*)buffer;
```

You need to `delete[]` your buffer to prevent a leak. 
You need to initialize `data` (MOUSERAWDATA) to prevent it from conditionally containing garbage.  How will the caller know that `raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEMOUSE` was true or false?

Have you considered just pinvoking GetRawInputData() directly per [Microsoft guidance](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1aeed6dc-cfa6-4469-9938-56dde5fc772c/how-do-i-work-with-handles-and-pointers?forum=csharpgeneral&prof=required):

```
public static extern int GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, RawInputCommand uiCommand, out RAWINPUT pData, ref int pcbSize, int cbSizeHeader);

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == (int)WindowMessages.RawInput)  // WindowMessages.RawInput = 0x00FF (WM_INPUT)
    {
        RAWINPUT input = new RAWINPUT();
        int outSize = 0;
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUT));

        outSize = Win32API.GetRawInputData(m.LParam, RawInputCommand.Input, out input, ref size, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));
        if (outSize != -1)
        {
            if (input.Header.Type == RawInputType.Mouse)
            {
                //input.Mouse.LastX;
                //input.Mouse.LastY;
            }
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. But your answer does not tell me why the value being passed is changing.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are building your .net and your c++ with the same bitness? Both 64-bit or both 32-bit. IntPtr will be a different size.